# HP 250 15.6 inch G9 Notebook Ubuntu 20.04 not reconising WIFI adapter, internal or external

Tags: wireless, hp

I have a new HP 250 15.6 inch G9 Notebook and I am trying to install a dual boot install of Ubuntu, alongside Windows 11.
Safe mode is disabled.
The install goes OK except the install does not recognize the WIFI adapter, internal or external (USB WIFI Adapter).
I have tried the solutions from this forum without avail.
Manual installation of the adapters has no effect.
I would appreciate this post being left open until a successful solution is found.
Kind regards

Requested output

```
sudo lsusb

[sudo] password for adrian: 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0064 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4601 (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46a8 (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P SATA AHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bc (rev 01)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b0 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b1 (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852


sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If you’ve tried other solutions on here, you’ve probably seen people provide specific hardware information about their machines. Guessing about which specific network devices might be in your machine is no fun at all. Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `sudo lsusb` and `sudo lspci`? This will make it much more likely that you receive an answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.